# Where am i able to see all leiningen templates?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Normally i could see them through:

lein new [TAB]

but this is no longer possible. Is there a central place, where they are stored?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easer to fix your shell and make it work again?

Comment: This could be useful: [Clj-templates](https://clj-templates.com)

Comment: @cfrick it is a bug

Comment: @MartinPůda This should be an answer. I have not the slightest clue, why a plugin list got accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin Puda says, there is a list at [clj-templates.com](https://clj-templates.com/)

Comment: Plugins are not templates

Comment: Sorry, that was a dumb mistake. Corrected.